# Как поступить с функцией?

Tags: python

Не знаю, что делать. То ли код переписывать, то ли костыли лепить.
Есть куча функций. К примеру возьмем 3.

```
astatic23()
astatic27()
bstatic27()
```

По итогу некого списка `[a, b, a,]` нужно подставлять первый элемент списка `a` к `static27()`, для того чтобы исполнить функцию.
Как это сделать?

```
list1 = [a, b, a,]
str(list[0]) + static() # Как это правильно сделать?
```

Как вообще поступать в таких случаях? Не получается полностью держать в голове весь замысел и периодически приходится выходить из ситауций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов - создать словарь с мапом ваших значений в функции. И потом вызывать их из этого словаря.

```
def astatic27(): print('astatic27')
def bstatic27(): print('bstatic27')

funcs_map = {'a': astatic27,
             'b': bstatic27}
           
lst = ['a', 'b', 'a']           

for el in lst:
    funcs_map[el]()
```

Вызовутся соответствующие функции.

```
astatic27
bstatic27
astatic27
```

Ещё можно собрать имя (как строку) и поискать функцию в атрибутах глобального/локального (или где ещё) пространства. Но это уже почти что хакинг.
Пример для глобальных функций:

```
for el in lst:
    globals()[el+'static27']()
```

Ещё как вариант, собирать имя функции и делать `eval`. Но так поступать вообще не советую.

Comment: Интересное решение. Спасибо. Не очень понял, зачем `print('astatic27')`?

Comment: Как их в словарь заводить? Если не предопределено что там будет a или x?

Comment: Я не могу в заранее карту начертить.

Comment: Я думаю, может как-то через литерал можно? Типа `f'''(`. Или `{}`
`a{f'''`

Comment: Если словарь не можете, но функции, к примеру, глобальные, то можно их достать по имени: `for el in lst:
    globals()[el+'static27']()`

Comment: Я слышал, что `global` плохое решение. В силу отсутствия опыта, не стал проверять. Это не так? Не могли бы кратко объяснить?

Comment: Использование глобальных переменных не рекомендуется (но не запрещено, просто это считается "плохим тоном"). В данном же случае это просто метод получения ссылки на функцию по её текстовому имени. А вообще, всё зависит от того как и где определены эти ваши функции. И можно ли, например, их засунуть в класс? И почему вы не можете заранее составить словарь соответствий (ведь имена функций же известны ибо должны быть определены)? По вашему примеру я предложил несколько вариантов решения. Конкретная реализация уже зависит от остального вашего кода.

Comment: Все более чем понятно! Спасибо!